# Something of a world citizen

Tags: riddle, geography

> New York City was my home for decades. Manhattan, to be exact. Even though I moved around several times, I generally stayed within a relatively small area. I lived on Fifth Avenue for almost forty years. Life was good. After New York I spent quite a while in downtown Chicago.
>
> It was in the late 1990s that I left the US and emigrated to Malaysia. I wouldn't use the word "abroad", though, since I consider myself something of a world citizen. I think you can already tell that I'm a "big city" kind of guy, and Kuala Lumpur certainly suited me very nicely.
>
> After Malaysia I did a short trip to Taiwan, a lovely country. Recently I've been residing here in the Middle East. I don't intend to make this place my permanent home, though – in fact, I already have plans to move into a neighboring country in a few years' time. After that, who knows?

Who am I? Where do I live? Where am I moving next?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are

> The world's tallest building

You were

> The Flatiron Building, then the Woolworth Building, then the Chrysler Building, then the Empire State Building in NYC; then the Sears/Willis Tower in Chicago, then the Petronas Towers in Kuala Lumpur, then Taipei 101 in Taiwan.

You are currently living in

> Dubai (The Burj Khalifa)

You might next be moving to

> Saudi Arabia, as the [Jeddah Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeddah_Tower) promises to be the world's first 1km-tall building when completed.

Comment: 3 minutes? Really? :D

Comment: Haha the sequence Chicago, Kuala Lumpur, Taiwan did it for me...think I was just lucky!! Great puzzle though! :D

Comment: I knew I should have gone with just "Asia" :P

Comment: This was better though -- definitely more accurate and you'd have been living in "Asia" for 20 years roughly...this way you were able to add some detail to the puzzle and still I don't think the correct answer is extremely obvious